# Getting pointer from native syscall in Java

Tags: java, native

Having the following Java code

```
Object[] params = new Object[] {new Object(), null}
int ret = lib.getClass().getMethod("syscall", int.class, Object[].class).invoke(
    lib, 116, params
);
```

where `116` is the code (on MacOS) for `gettimofday` system function,

how should I specify params correctly so that I can extract `timeval` struct containing the result (as specified by https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/gettimeofday.2.html)

Comment: Using JNA or - maybe - Project Panama to call this native function would probably get you further

Comment: As an aside, I don't see what using reflection brings you over calling the Java method `syscall` directly on `lib`.

Comment: And what's `lib` anyway?

Comment: The lib is native C lib defined as `lib = Native.load("c", CStdLib.class)`

Comment: @Mark how would you pass/read pointer using JNI? As `timeval` is a pointer to struct with the result.

Comment: To be clear, I didn't mention JNI, but [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) (which is an abstraction over JNI). And JNA definitely allows you to do such things.

Comment: It looks like you're already using JNA. In any case, your current code is a round-about way to execute `lib.syscall(116, new Object(), null)`, so I'd suggest calling that instead of using reflection. In any case, I suggest you study the [JNA documentation](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna#using-the-library), and maybe its tests and other code. I do use JNA occasionally, but it is not knowledge I have readily available in-depth.

Comment: @Mark thanks a lot. Your link helped to solve an issue. Will describe in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function expects specific struct as a first parameter which it will populate:

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({"sec", "usec"})
public static class Timeval extends Structure {
    /**
     * Seconds.
     */
    public long sec;

    /**
     * Microseconds.
     */
    public long usec;
}
```

Supplying parameters as follows succeed the call:

```
final Timeval timeval = new Timeval();
final Object[] params = new Object[]{timeval, null};
lib.syscall(116, params)
```

Result can be retrieved from `timeval.sec` and `timeval.usec`.

Thanks to ***@Mark Rotteveel*** for the hints.